# three.js gradient with canvas renderer

Tags: three.js

I know with the webgl renderer I can use vertexColors on a material to create a linear gradient.  According to the docs, this won't work for the canvas renderer.  How can I fall back on canvas renderer and still have a gradient?  I want it to be affected by ambient lighting, so I can't depend on an image texture.

Comment: Did you mean what you wrote -- ambient only? If so, you can use `Mesh.BasicMaterial`, represent the gradient with a texture, and darken the texture on-the-fly as the ambient light dims.

Comment: To clarify, I have a single ambient light for the scene that changes brightness.  With webgl renderer, the image textures are affected by that brightness.  When it falls back on cavas renderer, they are not.  I assume this is some sort of canvas renderer limitation.

How can I darken it on the fly other than with the ambient light?  When you say texture I am assuming an image - I am new to Three.Js

Basically I want a material with a linear gradient that can be affected by the lighting for both renderers.

Comment: Also, I am OK with doing it manually somehow as long as I can keep it in sync with the ambient light(which is tweened).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `CanvasRenderer` does not support `MeshLambertMaterial` and diffuse textures in combination.

If all you care about is ambient light, then you can use `MeshBasicMaterial` with a texture, and darken the texture on-the-fly to simulated ambient shading. (Actually, you could simulate any lighting this way.)

Note, this is really a hack.

Create a function to modify the texture based on ambient lighting. (`image` is the unshaded gradient in your case.)

```
function applyAmbient( mesh, image, ambientFactor ) { // 1.0 = lightest; 0.0 = darkest

    var canvas = mesh.material.map.image;

    var size = canvas.width;
    var size = canvas.height;

    // get context
    var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

    // copy image
    context.drawImage( image, 0, 0 );

    // apply ambient factor
    context.fillStyle = "rgba( 0, 0, 0, " + ( 1 - ambientFactor ) + " )";
    context.fillRect( 0, 0, size, size );

    return canvas;

}
```

Then, in the render loop, update the texture

```
applyAmbient( mesh, textureImage, ambientFactor );
mesh.material.map.needsUpdate = true; // important!
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mkP7q/

three.js r.62

Comment: This looks like what I want, but it yields an error on getContext.
"TypeError: Object #<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'getContext'"

Also, I assume the image param is a string of the image src?  By looking at this I assume I can pass material instead of mesh and also grab the src from the material.map.image.src.  I have a number of places where the material is used.

Comment: My comment was slightly ambiguous.  I get the error passing a mesh, imageSrc, ambient.  The part after that is regarding altering the function once I get it to work.

Comment: I added a fiddle to show one way to do it. I'll let you figure out your implementation details  :-)

Comment: I just noticed the generateTexture method works fine for canvas, but for webgl the alpha when using addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)') is all messed up.  Is there a way to change this so that alpha will work as expected when using webgl? I tried changing the getContext to webgl but it does not have the appropriate methods.

Comment: You need to make a new post for your new issue. Make it easy for people to help you by showing what you have tried, and provide a live example (jsfiddle) if possible.

Comment: Ok Thanks.  Posted a new question here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992340/three-js-draw-linear-gradient-texture-in-webgl

Comment: Awesome.  First true gradient I've been able to apply to a CanvasRenderer