# Three.Js draw linear gradient texture in webgl

Tags: three.js, webgl

With canvas renderer, I am using a function that draws a linear gradient.  I would like this to work with the webgl renderer as well, but it chokes on transparency.  The code is below and [here is a link to a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FtML5/1/) which demonstrates what I mean.

```
function generateTexture() {

var size = 512;

// create canvas
canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
canvas.width = size;
canvas.height = size;

// get context
var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

// draw gradient
context.rect( 0, 0, size, size );
var gradient = context.createLinearGradient( 0, 0, size, size );
gradient.addColorStop(0, '#99ddff'); // light blue 
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'transparent');
context.fillStyle = gradient;
context.fill();

return canvas;
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `WebGLRenderer`, you need to set `material.transparent = true`.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, transparent: true } );
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FtML5/3/

three.js r.62

Comment: Doh!  I knew I had to use that property when setting the opacity setting on the material itself, but didn't consider it when using a texture that has transparency.  Thanks for clearing that up for me lol.  Disappointed a bit that I didn't put 2 and 2 together.