# Linear gradient effect in threeJS

Tags: canvas, 3d, three.js, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a material (rn im using `MeshBasicMaterial`) with linear gradient (i.e go from black to transparent), where the idea is to create a "radar effect" (line in circle that goes around and fades).

I've achieved an "almost radar" effect using canvas as texture(and creating the LinearGradient there), but it isn't good enough as the "end" of the circle isn't completely transparent.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any code? Remember to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19992505/1980846