# Three.js doesn't fill shape with custom texture/color spectrum

Tags: colors, three.js

I have a requirement to draw a polygon and fill it with custom color spectrum.

- **For color spectrum**: after google, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992340/three-js-draw-linear-gradient-texture-in-webgl) which shows me how to generate a color spectrum the way I need.
- **For polygon**: I choose `THREE.Shape()` so I can define where to draw it.
- **Put things together**: it works fine with mono color like `material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.DoubleSide });` but it shows nothing when I use color spectrum. You can find my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/funnydinosaur/1axzjfpr/2/) (which I forked from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FtML5/3/)).

Please point me where I do thing wrong.

To not waste your time viewing code, here is snippet:

```
  var curveShape = new THREE.Shape();
  curveShape.moveTo(0, 0);
  curveShape.lineTo(5, 7);
  curveShape.lineTo(2, 9);
  curveShape.lineTo(8, 11);
  curveShape.lineTo(10, 15);
  curveShape.lineTo(9, 16);
  curveShape.lineTo(7, 20);
  curveShape.lineTo(0, 20);

  // geometry
  var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(curveShape);

  // material texture
  var texture = new THREE.Texture(generateTexture());
  texture.needsUpdate = true; // important!

  // material
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture,
    overdraw: 0.5,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });

  // mesh
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: Have a look at this [forum thread](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/texture-on-dynamically-created-object/2994?u=prisoner849).

Comment: @prisoner849 I tried but it didn't work

Comment: Your comment explains nothing. The thread has working examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are just using `moveTo()` in order to draw your shape. But this method only sets the internal current point of the shape to the given coordinates. To create a real contour, use methods like `lineTo()`.

```
var curveShape = new THREE.Shape();
curveShape.moveTo(0, 0); // define start point
curveShape.lineTo(5, 7); // draw a line from the current point to the given coordindates
```

Full example based on your code snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/12600/

Comment: thanks for your quick response, I changed from `moveTo()` to `lineTo()` and it does show the shape with color spectrum, but it doesn't spread color spectrum across the shape as I expect, do I need to set anything else to get it render that way? FYI: I updated my snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/funnydinosaur/1axzjfpr/

Comment: Changing the wrapping mode of the texture also changes the visual output. Are you looking for something like that? http://jsfiddle.net/1axzjfpr/16/

Comment: Not really, I'm looking for the shape covered by red at top 15%, then orange next 15%, etc like I define in texture. But it renders red almost entire shape and shift all other colors down to bottom 5%.